# CLGeoCoder doesnot return the exact data for the current location

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

In the simulator I set the location to

```
Latitude: 38.056709
Longitude: -78.6115
```

but the placemark that returns is of Virginia.

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation: APP_DELEGATE.userLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
{
    if([placemarks count] > 0)
    {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"placemark --- %@",placemark);
    }
}];
```

"**App.userlocation**" is the location that I get after updating the `locationmanager`

This is what I get in the console:

```
placemark ----
{
    City = "Charlottesville";
    Country = "United States";
    CountryCode = US;
    FormattedAddressLines = ("704 Grassmere Rd",
                             "Charlottesville",
                             "VA 22903-9214",
                             "United States");

    Name = "704 Grassmere Rd";
    PostCodeExtension = 9214;
    State = "Virginia";
    Street = "704 Grassmere Rd";
    SubAdministrativeArea = "Albemarle";
    SubLocality = "Samuel Miller";
    SubThoroughfare = 704;
    Thoroughfare = "Grassmere Rd";
    ZIP = 22903;
}
```

Comment: what is your exact problem?

Comment: @Volker the location that i had set is that of District of Columbia,but whats returning is Virginia

Comment: The placemark fits the coordinates, just checked in Maps app

Answer (score 1):

Check your coordinates, that's what Google Maps says for your coordinates:

```
Latitude: 38.056709
Longitude: -78.6115
```

[image]

`CLGeocoder` is actually right since those coordinates points in Virginia not District Columbia